# AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred. com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Code: 12500, message: 12500

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-keystore

I've added all 3 SHA-1 keys to Firebase:

```
// android debug keystore
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore

// production key
keytool -list -v -keystore MyProduction-key.jks -alias MyAliasOfMyProd-Key

// key found in Google Play
Google Play Console, Release management, App signing,
```

After adding the third key to the firebase console, it gives the 12500 error, when removing it shows errorCode 10.

```
AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
    com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Code: 12500, message: 12500: 
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.GoogleSignInHandler.onActivityResult(GoogleSignInHandler.java:112)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.idp.SingleSignInActivity.onActivityResult(SingleSignInActivity.java:142)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7762)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4603)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4652)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

I've also added my E-mail address in the "public settings".

[image]

- I haven't received an e-mail from firebase. Only a while back before I had unsafe DB rules, and this has been fixed.
- I also want to add that it was working fine on my debug environment for a while. But then it stopped working...?
- I made sure to download and replace the google-service.json after I added the 3 keys.

[image]

Comment: If you do a search for the text of the error, you will find *lots* of hits.  Be sure to read through those first, then edit the question to say everything you tried that didn't work.

Comment: i tried all those things already. I've added it to the ticket. The strange thing is it used to work on debug, but not anymore. It never did on production.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is many possibility, but try this:

1. go to [OAuth consent screen](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent).
2. Click `Edit App`. Note: Make sure it is your project (top left corner, beside Google APIs logo).
3. At the very bottom there is 3 links, try configured that

Comment: Configured. Doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

after make changes to your config on `firebase`, you have to download latest `google-service.json` file and place it to directed folder. then perform `invalidate cache and restart`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using google sign in then. Go to Google cloud platform>Credentials> click add Credentials and generate an OAuth Client id.

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

Answer (score 0):

there can so many reasons for the auth fail but check email on your firebase account.[image: follow the image]

Comment: have you checked on debug or release build?

Comment: i've updated my question. It used to work on debug. It never worked on production. It doesn't work on debug anymore either.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Check for errors somewhere in the logging?

Answer (score 0):

**The only solution is to Delete the key and generate new key with SHA1 from Google developer console.**